# C++ Class returning old values?

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out why this code,

```
class test{
    public:
    int number;
    test(int pass){
      number = pass;
    }
};

int main(){
   test x(3);
   test y(2);
   test z[2]={x,y};
   y.number = 1;
   cout << "z[0].number: " << z[0].number << endl;
   cout << "z[1].number: " << z[1].number << endl;
   cout << "x.number: " << x.number << endl;
   cout << "y.number: " << y.number << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comes up with this output,

```
z[0].number: 3
z[1].number: 2
x.number: 3
y.number: 1
```

Instead of this one,

```
z[0].number: 3
z[1].number: 1
x.number: 3
y.number: 1
```

How can I make the second output possible? I've searched for this for three days, and still no luck :(

Comment: `x = 2; y = x; x= 3;`. Now `y` is still `2`. Same thing.

Comment: And I never actually explained my upvote. Since it's valuable to newcomers, you did a lot right in this post. The title is relevant, you showed a short, self-contained, compilable example that reproduces your results, you showed what results you expected, and you showed what results you got. It was very easy to see what you were asking without needing more information. Each of those is better than what I see a lot of every day.

Comment: Let me guess, come from a Java or C# background? If so, may want to pick up a book and read a bit. There are near syntactically  equivalent constructs across the languages that have entirely different semantics.

Comment: By the way, if an answer helped you, the norm on SO is to click the checkmark beside it. This brings it to the top of the list so it's easily visible for others who come looking for answers to the same problem, so pick the one you want, keeping that in mind. Checking one shows that the question is actually answered.

Answer (score 21):

When you say:

```
test z[2] = {x, y};
```

`z` holds two copy-constructed instances of `test`. Since you didn't put in a copy constructor, it uses the default, which copies all data members. Thus, `z` contains a copy of `x` and a copy of `y`. That's why changing `y` doesn't change what's in `z`. It's not like Java where everything is a reference.

Comment: @AndyProwl, I'm finding it scary how I'm relating to Java a lot more now that my one course in it is almost done. I've confirmed what I already knew about how much I like using Java.

Comment: So wait, how can I make z[0] and z[1] a reference of x, and y?

Comment: @1Topcop, Roddy got close the first time. You can use an array of `std::reference_wrapper`, which acts like a reassignable reference (noted by a & in a declaration in C++). For example, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d0f9159540801230a38169f70f7333bc-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59. Note that this has alias semantics, not Java-like semantics (e.g. using assignment on the thing being referred to *will* change the reference). Java-like semantics are more like an array of pointers, but pointers have worse syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone! :D (including everyone on other posts)

Comment: @1Topcop: The usual way to get safe (Java-like) pointers is to use [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).  Before C++0x11, you needed to use [boost](http://www.boost.org/) to get these.  Note that these are reference-counted pointers, not garbage collected like Java; the difference is important to understand to avoid leaks.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, Good point, thanks. I was all caught up in the fact that we were talking about referring to actual other objects that I forgot about that aspect of the semantics.

Answer (score 7):

I initially wrote "You can make `z` be an array of *references* to `test` objects."

```
test &z[2] = {x,y};  // Wrong, wrong, wrong!
```

...but as I now realize - it's not as simple as that, as C++ does not allow arrays of references directly.

As @chris comments, in C++11 using [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) gets around this limitation.

```
std::reference_wrapper<test> z[2] = {x,y};
```

Comment: Pretty sure arrays of references aren't allowed by the standard.  (As far as it's concerned, references are basically aliases...they're not even required to take up any space.)

Comment: I can't get this to compile, and I'm pretty sure arrays of references are not allowed.

Comment: This is an excellent answer in conjunction with mine. This would give the same semantics as Java has. I think you can still use an array of `std::reference_wrapper` to get around the restrictions.

Comment: @Roby, `std::reference_wrapper` is an interesting thing, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your array `z` with `test z[2]={x,y};` you're actually making a *copy* of the values of `x` and `y` at the time you create the array. They are then two independent sets of values from then on, and even when you modify one, the other is still unchanged.

What you can do is create an array of pointers to the elements (since arrays of references aren't possible):

```
test* z[2] = {&x,&y};
cout << "z[0]->number: " << z[0]->number << endl;
cout << "z[1]->number: " << z[1]->number << endl;
```

But are you OK initializing the array and then taking references to it instead?

```
test z[2]={3, 2};
test& x(test[0]);
test& y(test[1]);
```

Comment: I like the backwards thinking here with respect to having the individual variables refer to the array elements. Of course the pointers are probably closest to the expected semantics as well.

Answer (score 1):

z[1] and y are not the same objects. What you've done is copy-initialized z[1] from the current value of y.

If you want the behavior, you'll have to do explicitly use pointer types (c++ does not allow arrays of references) like this:

```
class test{
    public:
    int number;
    test(int pass){
      number = pass;
    }
};

int main(){
   test x(3);
   test y(2);
   test *z[2]={&x,&y};
   y.number = 1;
   cout << "z[0]->number: " << z[0]->number << endl;
   cout << "z[1]->number: " << z[1]->number << endl;
   cout << "x.number: " << x.number << endl;
   cout << "y.number: " << y.number << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this, and it's giving me this error: declaration of 'z' as array of references? (Sorry, I'm still learning C++)

Comment: 1Topcop, see updated answer. C++ does not allow arrays of references

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't allow an array of references, but that's where `std::reference_wrapper` comes in handy:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    test x(1), y(2);

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<test>> z{ std::ref(x), std::ref(y) };

    x.number = 5;
    y.number = 3;

    std::cout << z[0].get().number << std::endl; // 5
    std::cout << z[1].get().number << std::endl; // 3
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/JAyown#view_edit_box)

This example also uses `std::vector`, which is recommended in place of your C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `z[1]` is a copy of `y`, not a reference to `y`. So after initializing array `z` any modification on `x` or `y` does not affects the value of `z[0]` or `z[1]`.